# How much total virtual cores are required to process 100GB of data in spark

Tags: apache-spark

For example if i choose 16 vcore with 10 worker nodes, so 16-1 (one core to store the hadoop daemons) * 10 (worker nodes) = 150 vcores (Total).
Is it safe to say that 150 vcores are required to process 100GB of data?
or is there any calculation should i need to consider before choosing the vcore?

Answer (score -1):

Number of Core in each node:-
A thumb rule is to use core per task. If tasks are not that much heavy then we can allocate 0.75 core per task.
Say if the machine is 16 Core then we can run at most 16 + (.25 of 16) = 20 tasks; 0.25 of 16 is added with the assumption that 0.75 per core is getting used.

Probably this link can help you better:
https://data-flair.training/forums/topic/hadoop-cluster-hardware-planning-and-provisioning/